# Add script content to page on runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, domdocument

I've tried to add some script tag with content to my index.html page on runtime After the page load and under the title tag, in the chrome console page I put the following

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "var a = 1" ;
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].appendChild(script);
```

I take this example from the SO forum but it doesnt work for me (the third statment are not doing anything

```
> 1.is it possible to do that in the console and update the document 
> 2.there is a way not do to do that in the console for example from external file...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add script in `head` instead of `title` and you should use text property if your want to add some variable to it like,

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.text = "var a = 1" ;
//-----^ it should be text not src, if you want external js then use src
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/185rdnv3/)

Comment: Thanks voted up Rohan but I dont see that the index.html was changed,any idea why?do I need to fire any event for that ?

Comment: Did you able to see that the index html was changed ?how nothing was changed for me in the console...

Comment: There is a way somehow to see the changed in the console after update the document ?Besouse just when I put alert in the script text I see that something happen...

Comment: Use [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) to see the resultant in console. And my [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/185rdnv3/) alerts too.

Answer (score 1):

```
script.src = "var a = 1" ;
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

This doesn't make sense. The `src` attribute of a `<script>` element must be set to the URL of a Javascript file, not the source of the script. As written, this code would attempt to load a script file **named** `var a = 1` (from the same directory as the current page).

If you want to run a script at runtime, you don't need to create a `<script>` element at all. Just run the code directly.

Comment: Thanks I've tried it but the index.html page was not changed ,any idea?

Comment: What do you mean, "the index.html page was not changed"? Running scripts, even ones that add elements, doesn't modify the page on the server. It only modifies the current state of the document in the browser.

Comment: but I should see that if its working in the console when I open the index.html in the source tab,correct ?

Comment: No. "View Source" displays the original source of the page; it doesn't reflect changes to the DOM made after the page was loaded.

Comment: Voted up!There is a way somehow to see the page content after it was changed by the console?

Comment: In most browsers you can get loads of useful debugging tools for HTML, javascript, CSS, etc by pressing F12. In Firefox I think you have to install the plugin first, it's called Firebug.